# Dynamic LINQ filter never retrieves correct results (UWP/XAML)

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, uwp

I have a `ObservableCollection<Miniature>MiniList` where my class is:

```
public class Miniature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Set { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

The names of these properties are fed into a ComboBox Where the user can select one (or choose ALL) and type in a search term to sort through the list.
 Heres the xaml for what its worth:

```
 <TextBlock Text="Search"
                       Style="{StaticResource RPTextBlock}"/>
            <ComboBox Name="FilterComboBox"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind FilterComboList}"                      
                      Style="{StaticResource RPCombo}"
                      FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  
                      SelectionChanged="FilterComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                      Loaded="comboBox_Loaded"/>
            <TextBlock Text="For"
                       Style="{StaticResource RPTextBlock}"/>
            <TextBox Name="SearchTextBox"
                     PlaceholderText="Search Term"/>
            <Button Content="&#xE094;"
                    Name="SearchIcon"                        
                    Style="{StaticResource RPButton}"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    FontSize="20"     
                    Click="SearchIcon_Click"/>
```

Originally my problem was: how to do `MiniList.AsQueryable().Where(m=>m.Property ==SearchTextBox.Text)` when I dont know ahead of time which property  will be chosen. After doing research dynamic linq seemed the way to go (though I am open to any solution). To that end I have this event:

```
private void SearchIcon_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FilterGridView(SearchTextBox.Text);
    SearchTextBox.Text = "";
}
```

that calls this method:

```
private void FilterGridView(string submission)
{
    var selected = FilterComboBox.SelectedValue;
    MVM = new MiniViewModel();//This is specific for passing a pregenerated list of minis, later might load from disk or db                            

    var templist = MVM.MiniCollection.AsQueryable()
        .Where("@0 = @1", selected, submission);
    MiniList.Clear();
    templist.ToList<Miniature>()
        .ForEach(m => MiniList.Add(m));
}
```

This never yields any results, even with the most basic examples, trying either the string or int properties. selected and submission are showing up correctly, and if for instance I choose Name in the combobox and type in "Succubus" the value of tempList is shown as

```
templist    {System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UWPMiniatures.Models.Miniature].Where(Param_0 => ("Name" == "Succubus"))}    System.Linq.IQueryable<UWPMiniatures.Models.Miniature> {System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<UWPMiniatures.Models.Miniature>}
```

It does clear the grid where my items appear though. Debugging and stepping through tempList, under Results View, always says "{       Empty   "Enumeration yielded no results"

I've tried this setup on a simple console program and couldnt get it to work, despite this being pretty similar to examples I've seen, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there is another way to do this.

Edit-I dont know how else to explain it. Let me try and fill in some gaps. I have a gridview in xaml whos source is `ObservableCollection<Miniature>MiniList`. For now the source is initialized with test values. I want to be able to filter the list by entering a search term and choosing one of the property values for the class from  a combobox, so that if for instance I choose the property Quantity and type 2 in the search box, it shows in the gridview all items with Quantity == 2. And as I said, trying the Dynamic extensions to linq did not work

Comment: This seems confusing, can you please share what exactly do you want to achieve? even a workflow would do

Answer (score 2):

The `@0`, `@1` etc. in Dynamic LINQ are *constant value* placeholders. Hence

```
.Where("@0 = @1", selected, submission);
```

generates the no sense string comparison

```
"Name" == "Succubus"
```

so it's not surprising that you don't get correct results.

What you really need is to embed the property name in the predicate string and only use placeholder for the value.

Assuming the `selected` variable contains the property name, the usage should be like this:

```
.Where(selected + " = @0", submission);
```

or with C#6 [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings):

```
.Where($"{selected} = @0", submission);
```